# infinit responsive carousel/slider using jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using [slick slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and I want to create something similiar to facebook's slider. What I mean is something like this:

[image: FaceBook]

In this slider, facebook adds items to its slider when I reach the end of right side. That's why in this picture there is no arrow  for go to left. You can go to facebook's game page by this [link](https://www.facebook.com/games/?from_bookmark=1). Since there is no way to define a function to be called upon reaching the end of slider, I use this code:

```
var intervalID   = 0  ;
function checkSlider(){
  if($("#slider .slick-next").hasClass('slick-disabled')){
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    ajaxCallToAddContent();
  }
}

function ajaxCallToAddContent(){
  //after adding contents, set t
  intervalID =  window.setInterval(function(){checkSlider();}, 500);
}
ajaxCallToAddContent();
```

Is there any way to do it using orginal slider?

P.S: If is there any better slider that provide me the same functionality as facebook slider has, that would be nice too!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean cyclic carousel slider, I think this one will help. This will be working in small devices and tablets also. You can have multiple carousels on the same page as well. Just replicate the "DIV"-"SpecDataWrap" and change the ID.

```
<div class="ContainerWrap">
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="AllSpecsDataWrap">
            <div class="SpecDataWrap" id="SpecDataWrap1">
                <div class="SpecDataSlides activeNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/lzem156s3/image1.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescRight">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecDataSlides InActiveNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/6cira13mb/image2.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescLeft">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecDataSlides InActiveNavSlide">
                    <img src="http://s19.postimg.org/f4zpxpor7/image3.jpg" />
                    <div class="SpecDesc SpecDescRight">
                        <h2>Choose to be unique.</h2>
                        <div class="SpecDescDetails">
                            Metal accents, colorful hues, real woods and leathers, and a customizable laser-etched signature offer thousands of ways to make your Moto X unique.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="SpecSlideNavigation">
                    <div class="leftNavSpec SpecSlideNav"></div>
                    <div class="bulletsNavSpec">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="activeImage"></li>
                            <li class="InActiveImage"></li>
                            <li class="InActiveImage"></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="clearFix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="RightNavSpec SpecSlideNav"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the JS and CSS code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/raju_sumit/Ld21vutz/

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I meant! I wanted it to load new items from server after reaching the end of cycle not going around!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is infinite scrolling. You can set this by setting the infinite property to true in the slick call.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.your-class').slick({
        infinite: true
      });
    });
```

Also, it would be helpful in the future if you could provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code so that we can see what your set up looks like!

Comment: I tried that before, it doesn't provide any means to add any new items to slider, it just goes back when reaches the end of slider!